# Can VNC screen definitions be added at start up?

Tags: 12.04, boot, startup, vnc

I have an AWS Ubuntu 12.04 GUI instance. I access it from my home Windows PC using VNC. Since the instance is stopped when not in use, every time I start it I have to SSH Terminal into it to run the VNC screen definitions commands. Only then I can start my VNC viewer into the GUI.

Is there a way to include the VNC screen definitions in a batch or startup script, so that they are created automatically every time I start the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using `x11vnc`, write a simple script and execute it in `/etc/rc.local` script.

Difference between x11vnc and traditional Unix VNC. `x11vnc` interacts directly with physical displays

A sample shell script

```sh
#!/bin/bash
x11vnc -safer -forever -display :0 -rfbauth ~/.vnc/passwd >/tmp/x11vnc.log 2>&1 &
```

Below I have included the install/config details I wrote for another question: [VNC on UBUNTU 13.04 - not showing full desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322006/vnc-on-ubuntu-13-04-not-showing-full-desktop/322505#322505)

**Install x11vnc**

`sudo apt-get install x11vnc`

**Create VNC password**

`x11vnc -storepasswd`

**NOTE**: defaults to `~/.vnc/passwd` file. Alternatively, use `vncpasswd` or
`-storepasswd` pass file
Store password pass as the VNC password in the file file. Once the password is stored the program exits. Use the password via "`-rfbauth file`". If called with no arguments, "`x11vnc -storepasswd`", the user is prompted for a password and it is stored in the file ~/.vnc/passwd. Called with one argument, that will be the file to store the prompted password in.

**Start x11vnc**

```sh
# Start x11vnc using ~/.vnc/passwd
x11vnc -safer -forever -display :0 -rfbauth /home/terry/.vnc/passwd
# less output to stderr -q -quiet
# this does not eliminate all informational output, it only reduces it
x11vnc -safer -forever -display :0 -rfbauth /home/terry/.vnc/passwd -q
# eliminate all output
x11vnc -safer -forever -display :0 -rfbauth /home/terry/.vnc/passwd 2>/dev/null 1>2&
```

**Change the VNC port to listen on**

```
-rfbport
```

The VNC port to listen on (a LibVNCServer option), e.g. 5900, 5901, etc. If specified as "-rfbport PROMPT" then the x11vnc -gui is used to prompt the user to enter the port number.

```
x11vnc -rfbport 5901
```

This force x11vnc to use port 5901 (this is VNC display :1.)

If something else is using that port x11vnc will exit immediately. If you do not supply the `-rfbport` option, it will autoprobe starting at 5900 and work its way up to 5999 looking for a free port to listen on.

**Send x11vnc to background**

```
x11vnc -safer -forever -display :0 -rfbauth /home/terry/.vnc/passwd -bg
```

Go into the background after screen setup. Messages to stderr are lost unless -o logfile is used.

**VNC password file**

The option `-rfbauth .vnc/passwd` provides additional protection by requiring a VNC password for every VNC viewer that connects. The `vncpasswd` or `storepasswd` programs, or the `x11vnc -storepasswd` option can be used to create the password file. `x11vnc` also has the slightly less secure `-passwdfile` and `-passwd XXXXX` options to specify passwords.